# opencl is giving wrong results for double data type?

Tags: c, opencl

I am very new to OpenCl.

Problem: i am initializing an array of 10 elements with value of -1 in Host. I am passing the same array as input to device and incrementing each element and then receiving back the array as output through Buffer. Then again, sending back the same output array as input to host and receiving back incremented output buffer. This is done in loop.

Issue: When i am having the data type of array as float/int, Program is working fine. But when i am making the datatype as double of the array it is not giving me the desired results.
Please suggest where i am missing? Any help/suggestion/keywords will be a great help. Thanks in advance.

**Code for float data type of array:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif


#define MEM_SIZE (10)
#define MAX_SOURCE_SIZE (0x100000)


int main() {
    float input[MEM_SIZE], output[MEM_SIZE];
    int go, i;
    for (i = 0; i < MEM_SIZE; i++) {
        input[i] = -1.0;
        output[i] = -1.0;
    }
    FILE *fp;
    cl_device_id device_id = NULL;
    cl_context context = NULL;
    cl_command_queue command_queue = NULL;
    cl_program program = NULL;
    cl_kernel kernel = NULL;
    cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
    cl_uint ret_num_devices;
    cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
    cl_int ret;
    size_t source_size;
    char *source_str;
    fp = fopen("calc_float.cl", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    source_str = (char*)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
    source_size = fread(source_str, 1, MAX_SOURCE_SIZE, fp);
    fclose(fp);


    /*Initialization*/
    /* Get Platform and Device Info */
    ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices);

    /* Create OpenCL context */
    context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);

    /* Create Command Queue */
    command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &ret);

    /*Initialization complete*/

    cl_mem inputBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY|CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, MEM_SIZE * sizeof(float),(void *) input, NULL);
    cl_mem outputBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY , MEM_SIZE * sizeof(float), NULL, NULL);


    /* Create Kernel Program from the source */
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **)&source_str,(const size_t *)&source_size, &ret);

    /* Build Kernel Program */
    ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    /* Create OpenCL Kernel */
    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "calc", &ret);

    /* Set OpenCL Kernel Parameters */
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&inputBuffer);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&outputBuffer);

    /* Execute OpenCL Kernel */
    ret = clEnqueueTask(command_queue, kernel, 0, NULL,NULL);
    double x = 10, io;
    size_t global_work_size[1] = {MEM_SIZE};
    for (io = 0; io < x; io++) {
        inputBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY|CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, MEM_SIZE * sizeof(float),(void *) output, NULL);
        ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&inputBuffer);
        ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, global_work_size, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

        ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, outputBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, MEM_SIZE * sizeof(float), output, 0, NULL, NULL);
        for (go = 0; go < MEM_SIZE; go++) {
            printf("output[%d] = %f\n",io, go, output[go]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");

    }


    /* Finalization */
    ret = clFlush(command_queue);
    ret = clFinish(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    ret = clReleaseProgram(program);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(inputBuffer);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(outputBuffer);
    ret = clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseContext(context);

    return 1;
}
```

calc_float.cl file for above code:

```
__kernel void calc(__global float* in, __global float* out)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        out[i] = in[i] + 1;
    }
}
```

**Code for double data type of array:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif

#define MEM_SIZE (10)
#define MAX_SOURCE_SIZE (0x100000)


int main() {
    double input[MEM_SIZE], output[MEM_SIZE];
    int go, i;
    for (i = 0; i < MEM_SIZE; i++) {
        input[i] = -1.0;
        output[i] = -1.0;
    }
    FILE *fp;
    cl_device_id device_id = NULL;
    cl_context context = NULL;
    cl_command_queue command_queue = NULL;
    cl_program program = NULL;
    cl_kernel kernel = NULL;
    cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
    cl_uint ret_num_devices;
    cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
    cl_int ret;
    size_t source_size;
    char *source_str;
    fp = fopen("calc_double.cl", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    source_str = (char*)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
    source_size = fread(source_str, 1, MAX_SOURCE_SIZE, fp);
    fclose(fp);


    /*Initialization*/
    /* Get Platform and Device Info */
    ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices);

    /* Create OpenCL context */
    context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);

    /* Create Command Queue */
    command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &ret);

    /*Initialization complete*/

    cl_mem inputBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY|CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, MEM_SIZE * sizeof(double),(void *) input, NULL);
    cl_mem outputBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY , MEM_SIZE * sizeof(double), NULL, NULL);


    /* Create Kernel Program from the source */
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **)&source_str,(const size_t *)&source_size, &ret);

    /* Build Kernel Program */
    ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    /* Create OpenCL Kernel */
    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "calc", &ret);

    /* Set OpenCL Kernel Parameters */
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&inputBuffer);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&outputBuffer);

    /* Execute OpenCL Kernel */
    ret = clEnqueueTask(command_queue, kernel, 0, NULL,NULL);
    double x = 10, io;
    size_t global_work_size[1] = {MEM_SIZE};
    for (io = 0; io < x; io++) {
        inputBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY|CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, MEM_SIZE * sizeof(double),(void *) output, NULL);
        ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&inputBuffer);
        ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, global_work_size, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

        ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, outputBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, MEM_SIZE * sizeof(double), output, 0, NULL, NULL);
        for (go = 0; go < MEM_SIZE; go++) {
            printf("output[%d] = %lf\n",io, go, output[go]);
        }
        printf("\n\n");

    }


    /* Finalization */
    ret = clFlush(command_queue);
    ret = clFinish(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    ret = clReleaseProgram(program);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(inputBuffer);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(outputBuffer);
    ret = clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseContext(context);

    return 1;
}
```

calc_double.cl file for above code:

```
__kernel void calc(__global double* in, __global double* out)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        out[i] = in[i] + 1;
    }
}
```

compilation of program:

```
gcc program.c -o doublesimulation -l OpenCL -I /usr/local/test/AMD-APP-SDK-v2.9-RC-lnx32/include/ -L /usr/local/test/AMD-APP-SDK-v2.9-RC-lnx32/lib/x86
```

i also tried adding following checks, but it didn't help:

```
#ifdef cl_khr_fp64
    #pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable
#elif defined(cl_amd_fp64)
    #pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_amd_fp64 : enable
#else
    #error "Double precision floating point not supported by OpenCL implementation."
#endif
```

Operating System: Centos5 32bit with AMD graphics card

Comment: is clEnqueueReadBuffer executed successfully? Always check error for the OpenCL API, those are potential helpers.

Answer (score 4):

Check that your GPU supports double precision:

```
cl_uint native_double_width;    
clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_DOUBLE, sizeof(cl_uint), &native_double_width, NULL);

if(native_double_width == 0){
    printf("No double precision support.\n");
}
```

If native double vector width is equal to 0, double precision isn't supported ([clGetDeviceInfo description](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html))

Comment: Fully agree, using OpenCL witch is a communication API with the GPU and not checking the return values is completely unsafe. Exactly as using sockets and discarding the return values.

Comment: One small caveat with this method is that CL_DEVICE_NATIVE_VECTOR_WIDTH_* constants were only added in version 1.1 of the standard so version 1.0 implementations should fail.  The correct way of checking for double precision support, and generally the presence of any extension, is to check the extensions returned for the platform and device.  Admittedly, this is a minor point since I don't know of any current OpenCL implementations that are stuck on version 1.0, but I'm pedantic.

Comment: Thanks for correction. Method, which must work for every OpenCL Device: check for cl_khr_fp64 extension, and don't be confused by vendor-specific extensions, e. g. cl_amd_fp64.

Comment: Thanks @RomanArzumanyan.. My native_double_width value is coming 1. That states it supports double. Am i missing something in code. Because float and int data type is returning perfectly. Might be i am missing something for double?? and sorry for late reply.

Comment: First thing I saw in your code - you don't wait for kernel to finish. Either wait for command queue to finish, or (better), wait for event. Reading buffer, which is in use by kernel is undefined.